# Javascript create a quiz with "text box"

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a questionnaire but instead of using "radio buttons" I would like the user to be able to write the answer to each of the questions in a "text box" but I do not see how to do it. Could you please help me ?

In my console I have this errors :
Quiz.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: nextButton . addEventListener is not a function
at questionaire (Quiz. js:33)
at Quiz. js:100

```js
const questions = [
  { 
    question: 'What platform are you on?',
    answers: 'Stackoverflow',
    points: 5
  },
  { 
    question: '40 + 2?',
    answers: 42,
    points: 1
  },
  { 
    question: 'How much is 7*6',
    answers: 42,
    points: 1
  }
];

// a simple generator that is used in the questionaire
function *questionsGenerator( questions ) {
  yield* questions;
}

// creates a questionaire, with forward only options (due to the use of the generator function)
// all variables are locally scoped, when all questions were answered, the onCompleted callback would be called
// it returns an object with nextQuestion function though it could call nextButton internally, and you just have to call the function once if you would want to change it
const questionaire = ( query, nextButton, target, onCompleted ) => {
  let score = 0;
  let iterator = questionsGenerator( query );
  let question = null;
  let selectedAnswer = -1;
  
  nextButton.addEventListener('click', nextQuestion);
  
  function evaluateAnswer() {
    if (!question) {
      // no question yet
      return;
    }
    if (selectedAnswer < 0) {
      return;
    }
    if (question.correct === selectedAnswer) {
      score += question.points;
    }
    return;
  }
  
  function nextQuestion() {
    evaluateAnswer();
    question = iterator.next();
    // this is a bit of a hack to check if we just had the last question or not
    if (question.done) {
      nextButton.removeEventListener('click', nextQuestion);
      onCompleted( score );
      return;
    }
    question = question.value;
    drawUI();
  }
  
  function drawUI() {
    // disable next button
    nextButton.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    selectedAnswer = -1;
    // remove existing items
    Array.from( target.childNodes ).forEach( child => target.removeChild( child ) );
    // create new questions (if available)
    const title = document.createElement('h1');
    title.innerHTML = question.question;
    target.appendChild( title );
    
    question.answers.map( (answer, i) => {
      const el = document.createElement('input');
      el.type = 'text';
      el.name = 'answer';
      el.value = i;
      el.id = 'answer' + i;
      el.addEventListener('change', () => { 
        selectedAnswer = i; 
        nextButton.removeAttribute('disabled'); 
      } );
      const label = document.createElement('label');
      label.setAttribute('for', el.id );
      label.innerHTML = answer;
      
      const container = document.createElement('div');
      container.appendChild(el);
      container.appendChild(label);
      return container;      
    } ).forEach( a => target.appendChild( a ) );
  }
  
  return {
    nextQuestion
  }
};

// create a questionaire and start the first question
questionaire(
  questions, 
  document.querySelector('input'[id="text"]).value,
  document.querySelector('#btnNext'), 
  document.querySelector('#questionaire'), 
  score => alert('You scored ' + score ) 
).nextQuestion();
```

```html
<h1>questionnaire</h1>
<div id="questionaire"></div>
<input type="text" id="text"/>
<div class="toolstrip">
  <button id="btnNext" type="button">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't edit your question into something useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `questionaire` function has 4 inputs `( query, nextButton, target, onCompleted )` but you're calling it with more. Specifically, the second input (`document.querySelector('input'[id="text"]).value`) is just wrong, you should remove it.

```
questionaire(
  questions, 
  document.querySelector('input'[id="text"]).value,
  document.querySelector('#btnNext'), 
  document.querySelector('#questionaire'), 
  score => alert('You scored ' + score ) 
)
```

Other than that, please provide your HTML code as well so we can reproduce the case and see what else is wrong.

Comment: I just added my html code in my topic ! ^^

Comment: But if I delete it, how will we be able to retrieve the response that the user has entered in a "text box"? :(

Comment: I'm sorry, there are so many wrong things here to point them all out... you reassign the variable `question` many times, you call `question.map` when it's not an array, you declare global functions inside your creation function. I suggest you watching some courses

Comment: Can you correct my code please? I do not understand and I have already been unsuccessfully searching all day for how to solve my problems :(

Comment: You should have some more basics on javascript, then rewrite the code step by step and by testing each part of the code, before putting everything together.

Comment: I have to hand in this work tonight, I don't have much time :/ Can you correct my cpde please ? I will be very grateful to you

Answer (score 0):

Just add an input with `type="text"` and then get the value with `document.querySelector(...).value`

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do this? Where do I write it in my code? :O

Comment: I have make this but I have this error : 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at questionaire (Quiz.js:34)
    at Quiz.js:101
questionaire @ Quiz.js:34
(anonymous) @ Quiz.js:101

Comment: Are you sure the query selector finds the element?

Comment: I don't no, I just add this in my file.html : <input type="text" id="text"/>    and I add   document.querySelector('input'[id="text"]).value,  in the end of my quiz.js : questionaire(
  questions, 
  document.querySelector('input'[id="text"]),
  document.querySelector('#btnNext'), 
  document.querySelector('#questionaire'), 
  score => alert('TYour score ' + score ) 
).nextQuestion();

Comment: No, your querySelector won't find it, because it is wrong.  This would be correct: document.querySelector('input[id="text"]')

Comment: I just tried but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: I have this error : Quiz.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: nextButton.addEventListener is not a function
    at questionaire (Quiz.js:33)
    at Quiz.js:100

Comment: What value does nextButton have?

Comment: It have : nextButton.addEventListener('click', nextQuestion);   
This is the button to go to the next question